# Jsonifying an array

Tags: python, json, boto

I have the following:

```
def jsonify(ar):
    json.dumps(ar._data)

jsonify(getFromTable())
```

getFromTable returns an array of boto objects. Each of those objects has a _data element. However ar._data does not work. It does not have the attribute _data.

How can I make a singular json from multiple objects. Or is it impossible?

My work around for this is:

```
def jsonify(ar):
    str=""
    for i in ar:
        str+=json.dumps(i._data)
    print str
    return str
jsonify(getFromTable())
```

However I would still preffer to print them all in one json blob. Does anyone know how?

**Solved below with help from mGilson**

Also just as an fyi:

I'm using boto, dynamodb2, python, and pulling from a lazy evaluation resultSet returned by querying my table.

Comment: You'd need to put all the objects into a `list` (or `tuple`) and dump that.  As it is though, I must say that I don't quite understand the question here ...

Comment: Oh that would make sense, on sec let me test that

Comment: I would suggest that if you're trying to extract something from a 3rd party object using any member starting with underscore (e.g. `_data`) that you're probably not doing the right thing.

Comment: @NickBastin can you explain that? I'm using boto, dynamodb2, and testing my ability to scan from a table. A table returns a list of boto elements that use lazy evaluation.

Comment: for example __len__ is a ok thing to do, how does _data distinguish itself as undesirable?

Answer (score 0):

@mGilson, thank you. That was the correct way to solve that.

For anyone curious here is the implementation that I used.

```
def getFromTable():
    global table
    #t = table.scan(thirdKey__eq="Anon")
    t = table.scan()
    arr = []
    for a in t:
        arr.append(a)
    return arr

def jsonify(ar):
    str = json.dumps(ar)
    print str
    return str

def createListFromBotoObj(obj):
    myList = []
    for o in obj:
        myList.append(o._data)
    return myList
jsonify(createListFromBotoObj(getFromTable()))
```

Which prints the expected result:

> [{"secondKey": "Doe", "thirdKey": "Anon", "firstKey": "John"}, {"secondKey": "G", "thirdKey": "Company", "firstKey": "P"}, {"secondKey": "T", "thirdKey": "Engineer3", "firstKey": "allen"}, {"secondKey": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "firstKey": "booperface"}, {"secondKey": "The Builder", "thirdKey": "Sadness", "firstKey": "Bob"}]

In case anyone is wondering I'm using this to test how I will implement my actual database.